# Ubuntu Laravel storage/logs/cron.log permission denied

Tags: cron, logs, laravel

I have Ubuntu 18.04, Laravel and PHP7.4.
When I do for example command `ls` I have the list of folders and:

```
user1@bpl:/var/www/html/storage$ ls
app  framework  logs
You have new mail in /var/mail/user1
```

When I do `cat /var/mail/user1` I have content of the file:

```
From user1@bpl  Tue Mar  3 14:30:01 2020
Return-Path: <user1@bpl>
X-Original-To: user1
Delivered-To: user1@bpl
Received: by bpl (Postfix, from userid 1000)
        id 3264910126D; Tue,  3 Mar 2020 14:30:01 +0000 (UTC)
From: root@bpl (Cron Daemon)
To: user1@bpl
Subject: Cron <user1@bpl> $PHP $ARTISAN transaction:verify >> $LOGS 2>&1
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-Cron-Env: <PHP=/usr/bin/php>
X-Cron-Env: <ARTISAN=/var/www/html/artisan>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGS=/var/www/html/storage/logs/cron.log>
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/home/user1>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=user1>
Message-Id: <20200303143001.3264910126D@bpl>
Date: Tue,  3 Mar 2020 14:30:01 +0000 (UTC)

/bin/sh: 1: cannot create /var/www/html/storage/logs/cron.log: Permission denied
```

Permissions of folder logs looks like:

```
user1@bpl:/var/www/html/storage$ ls -al
total 20
drwxrwxr-x  5 www-data www-data 4096 Feb 24 14:36 .
drwxr-xr-x 13 www-data www-data 4096 Feb 29 02:06 ..
drwxrwxr-x  3 www-data www-data 4096 Feb 28 15:13 app
drwxrwxr-x  6 www-data www-data 4096 Feb 24 14:36 framework
drwxrwxr-x  2 www-data www-data 4096 Mar  3 14:02 logs
```

Task Transaction verify is from cron. This task is added to the user cron. 
How to enable writting these logs to this file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the directory permissions allow writing (file creation) for the owner and group, add yourself to the `www-data` group with

```
sudo adduser $USER www-data
```

The new group membership will take effect at the next login.